# Pass data model through ajax post in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am having partial modal view:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Bootstrap Dialog</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn-primary btn" id="btnOK" onclick="">OK</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-default btn" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancel" onclick="">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnOK').click(function () {
                var data = {Name: "dsdsd", Email: "dsdsd@sdsd.com", Mobile: 05456545}
                //$.post(url, data)
                console.log(data);
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

But when I hit OK button nothing happens, there is nothing in my console.
I want to be able to pass to my controller my data and then to show some success message as another popup or something.

So, to be clear, modal open OK with this code on the main page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-block">Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-url='@Url.Action("_ContactForm","Home")'></div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn-block').click(function () {
                var url = $('#myModal').data('url');

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('#myModal').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

but when I hit OK on modal, nothing happens. Why?

Comment: So you mean `$('#btnOK').click` doesn't fire? If that's inside a partial view, and you loaded the partial view via AJAX, it won't work because scripts downloaded via AJAX don't get executed (for security reasons, largely).

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding `type="text/javascript"` to your script tag inside @section-scripts.
Maybe ASP.net enforces the HTML 4 spec, in which 'type' is a required attribute of the script tag?

I don't know much about ASP.net and would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.